# Selenium element can not be found within iframe

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve a JSON element, the problem is that in the source code it doesn't exist, but I can find it via inspect element.

I have tried with

```
C.driver.findElement(By.id("ticket-parsed"))
```

and via XPath

```
C.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ticket_parsed\"]"));
```

and I can't find it.

Also

```
C.driver.switchTo().frame("html5-frame"); 
System.out.println(C.driver.findElement(By.id("ticket_parsed"))); 
C.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

i get

```
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (1f75e50635f9dd5b9535a149a027a447)] -> id: ticket_parsed]
```

on

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(0) or driver.switchTo().frame(1)
```

i get that the frame doesn't exists

and at last i tried

```
 WebElement frame = C.driver.findElement(By.id("html5-frame"));
 C.driver.switchTo().frame(frame.getAttribute("ticket_parsed"));
```

an i got a null pointer exception

**Here's an image of the source**:

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "... on source code it doesn't exists, but i can find it via inspect element."  - This is only possible if some script is generating your html markup.  If that is the case, you may need to tell Selenium to wait a second or two before attempting to find that element (that way you give the script enough time to create the element in the DOM).

Comment: Does it is in iFrame?

Comment: Thumbs up for question with inspect element code!!! @fx86f

Comment: At last i can crab the element i want via document.getElementById("html5-frame").contentDocument.getElementById("ticket_parsed");
whats the equivalent in selenium ?

Comment: i tried to get the result from the js command with                System.out.println(jse.executeScript("return document.getElementById(\"html5-frame\").contentDocument.getElementById(\"ticket_parsed\");"));
 but it didn't work ,the result was [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@d7c5b237 -> unknown locator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well!

The element `#ticket-parsed` is in iFrame. So, you can click it without getting into an iframe.

**Here is the code to switch to iFrame**,

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name");
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frame_index);
```

---

**In your case,**

```
driver.switchTo().frame("html5-frame");
```

After switching into the iframe, you can click that element using either XPath or CSS.

```
C.driver.findElement(By.id("ticket-parsed"))
```

---

**NOTE**:
After completing the operation inside the iframe, you have to again return back to the main window using the following command.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: C.driver.switchTo().frame("html5-frame");
System.out.println(C.driver.findElement(By.id("ticket_parsed")));
C.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

and the result was org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ticket_parsed"}

Comment: Try using driver.switchTo().frame(0) or driver.switchTo().frame(1)

Comment: I tried driver.switchTo().frame(0).. it didn't find any frame,
for the previews solution i added more time just in case and the printed value was [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (1f75e50635f9dd5b9535a149a027a447)] -> id: ticket_parsed]

I have tried firefox ie and chrome with the exactly same results 

the reason  why i want "ticket_parsed" is because i want to compare it with another string

Comment: Please share few lines of your code. Also, check the count of iframe. @fx

Comment: Then go through theses documents [working with iframe](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver) and [Handline iframe](http://www.assertselenium.com/webdriver/handling-iframes-using-webdriver/)

Comment: with these   
C.driver.switchTo().frame("html5-frame");  
                System.out.println(C.driver.findElement(By.id("ticket_parsed")));  
                C.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
i get [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (1f75e50635f9dd5b9535a149a027a447)] -> id: ticket_parsed]   

with driver.switchTo().frame(0) 
i get that the frame doesn't exist   

and i have tried this   
WebElement frame = C.driver.findElement(By.id("html5-frame"));
C.driver.switchTo().frame(frame.getAttribute("ticket_parsed"));  
and i got null pointer exception

,sorry for ugly post

Comment: is there any possibility that [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (1f75e50635f9dd5b9535a149a027a447)] -> id: ticket_parsed] is correct and i am accessing it with the wrong way ?

Comment: i tried it again just because of curiosity , at last a .getText was the problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a solution with my excising setup,but i did found a js command which gets the object correctly

```
 document.getElementById("html5-frame").contentDocument.getElementById("ticket_parsed")
```

you can integrate js commands like this

```
 JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
 js.executeScript(*yourCommandHere*);
```

if you want to get the output of the command just add the word return before your command (in this specific situation it didn't work but in any other situation it did)

```
 *TypeOfData* foo = js.executeScript(return *yourCommandHere*);
```

at last because of limited time i had to use unorthodox methods like taking screenshots and comparing the images if they are exactly the same

Thanks for the help